# Pagination issue in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to sort out the pagination problem in iframe. The problem is this when I go next using pagination it is working fine but height of iframe is not increasing according to content.

You can check here

```
http://fsportal.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
username: test@liferay.com
pass : $PlayBuff2607$
Upi:kjhkjh
```

Comment: Do not ever provide access to restricted website areas in a public forum

Comment: its a test server and i am in big problem that's why i providing access. Can you solve this problem?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."

Comment: Required reading: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/472495).

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that iframe height is not increasing.

Search for **postmessage**. You can setup communication between the iframe and the parent page using it. When a change of height happens in the document inside an iframe, a javascript should send the height to your parent page, where another javascript should change the height of the iframe element.